# Monitoring the progress of a python script online, or on my phone, or another computer

Tags: python

I have a python script that runs for a few hours. There is some probability of it failing or hanging. Therefore, I would like to find a way to monitor this script's progress while away from the computer it runs on. I have been looking into multiple options, but none of them are robust and straightforward enough.

If someone has some ideas, I'd love to hear them.

Here are some options I considered:

- The computer running python is connected to my dropbox account. Therefore, I could write an HTML file to my dropbox. This would work on other computers. I could open the HTML file on another computer and refresh the page to get the latest version. However, this would not work on my phone. It would also not push any updates (not necessary, but that would be a great feature).
- I looked into building an online dashboard that would visualize data. The idea would be to update the data as the script runs, thereby getting the script's latest state. I looked into plotly and anvil. However, I could not find a way of programmatically updating the data online.

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple quick fix you could make a log file and have it update it at intervals. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: As this is just a suggestion, this is not suitable for an answer, this is more suitable as a comment (when you have enough karma). To improve your answer, you can add a code snippet for the logging that you suggested, such as what module to use, what functions to use etc.